# prevent adding duplicate items to the basket

Tags: javascript, php, shopping-cart

I have created a basket in my PHP form where users can insert their selected movies to it.

### Question:

How can I prevent adding duplicate movies to this basket (selected movie list)?

Here is my code: (Sorry, I didn't paste all the code since it was too long)

```
<div id="basket">
   <div id="basket_left">
       <h4>Selected Movies</h4>
       <img id="basket_img" src="http://brettrutecky.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/11.png" />
   </div>
   <div id="basket_right">
       <div id="basket_content">
          <span style="font-style:italic">Your list is empty</span>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var master_basket = new Array();
$(document).ready(function () {$("input[id='selectType']").change(function(){

 // AUTO_COMPLETION PART

$('#btnMove').on('click', function(d) {
    console.log(master_basket);
    d.preventDefault();
    var selected = $("#q").val();
    if (selected.length == 0) {
        alert("Nothing to move.");
        d.preventDefault();
    } else {
        var obj = {
            "movie_name":selected,
               "movie_info": ""
          };
        addToBasket(obj);
    }
    $("#q").val("");
  });
});

function addToBasket(item) {
       master_basket.push(item);
       showBasketObjects();
    }
function showBasketObjects() {
       $("#basket_content").empty();
       $.each(master_basket, function(k, v) {
             $("#basket_content").append("<div class='item_list'>" + v.movie_name + "<a class='remove_link' href='" + k + "'><img width='20' src='http://i61.tinypic.com/4n9tt.png'></a></div>");
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally wouldn't suggest using javascript to prevent this duplication thing since anyone could modify it and manually cause this problem, you should prevent the duplication both in php and javascript.

Anyway to accomplish what you want in the script I think it's enough to modify part of your code to this:

```
var master_basket = new Array();
selectedMovies = {};

  ///////

} else {
    var obj = {
        "movie_name":selected,
           "movie_info": ""
      };
    if(!selectedMovies.hasOwnProperty(selected)){
        addToBasket(obj);
        selectedMovies[selected] = obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your function to

```
 function addToBasket(item) {

    var ifExists = false;

    for (i = 0; i < master_basket.length; ++i) {
      if(master_basket[i] == item)
        ifExists = true;

    }


    if(!ifExists)
       master_basket.push(item);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your code, but when I click "add to list" button, it does not add the movie name to the basket, also I see in the console that for the first time that I insert a movie name it shows `Array [ Object ]`, if I insert the same movie for the second time, I see `Array [ Object, object ]` in the console,..

Comment: @mOna can u provide jsfiddle ?

Comment: @mona coz you are passing object to array

Comment: I didn't work with fiddle.. how can I put my code there and share with you?

Comment: just signup , and you can share your sample working code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64623/discussion-between-codingant-and-mona).